# How to make a fixed blurring overlay in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, overlay, blur

[I would like to implement this overlay bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHoXN.png)

[This is what i reached lately (i just want to blur the part below the overlay bar portion, everything else is not a problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGsJx.jpg)

The crucial part is that it must blur the portion of screen below itself. I have no clue about how should i do it, i tried everything (like setting up a transparent container and blur it, but the transparent color turns out to be black :/ ).

This is how i currently implement the navigation bar with a container over it:

```
Widget _navigationBarAndOverlay() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        OverlayBarWidget(),
        _navigationBar(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

And this is the OverlayBarWidget code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      height: 85,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Center(child: Text("Nothing to do"),),
    );
  }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT**:

In the end i managed to do it just few minutes later, so i won't assign the best answer.
The solution is using a Stack instead of a Column: the overlay part will actually overlay the interface instead of being put below. In order to do it, you need to give your bottomAppBar a precise dimension (use a SizeBox, as below) and use a Positioned for the overlay bar positioning

```
Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Scaffold(
              body: TabBarView(
                controller: tabController,
                ...
              ),
              bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(
                height: 57,
                child: _navigationBar(),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 57,
              child: ClipRect(
                child: BackdropFilter(
                  filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaY: 16, sigmaX: 16),
                  child: OverlayBarWidget(),
                ),
              ),
            )
)
```

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFZjb.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

You can try `BackDropFilter`

This kind of effects are relatively **expensive**, use them with caution!

*Important*: Wrap your container with `ClipRect` widget, otherwise the entire screen will take the BackDropFilter effect.

```
ClipRect(
  child: Container(
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('assets/your-image.png'),
      ),
    ),
    child: BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5.0, sigmaY: 5.0),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.0),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Play with the values to get different effects

```
sigmaX: 5.0
sigmaY: 5.0
withOpacity: 0.0
```

Making a comparison, at this point you get something like this:

[image]

Now, if you want to *display information over that image*, you can just use the previous code in a `Stack()`, and add some `Positioned()` `Text()`

```
Stack(   
  children: <Widget>[
    ClipRect( ... ),
    Positioned(top: 30, left: 30, child: Text("Some Info"),
    Positioned(top: 60, left: 30, child: Text("Some more Info"),
  ], )
```

You can get something like this

### [image]

[BackDropFilter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BackdropFilter-class.html)

Flutter video about BackDropFilter --> https://youtu.be/dYRs7Q1vfYI

Comment: Thanks, but that wouldn't be enough. Look back at the question if you're curious to know how i solved it :)